# Reading values from app propertis and check if contains?

Tags: java

I have this in my app propertis:

```
deactivate.setup ={'user_deleted','user_deactivated','admin_deleted','admin_deactivated'}
```

This is how i read properties:

```
@Value("${deactivate.setup}")
private List<String> deactivate;
```

But when i use this it always return false:

```
if(deactivate.contains(getCode(resource))){}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the value of `deactivate.setup` in the application properties.

In your case, the list values are as below

[image]

As you can see `{` and `'` characters are in the list. So change `deactivate.setup` value with `user_deleted,user_deactivated,admin_deleted,admin_deactivated`.